# How to get sum of multiple records in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    TC.F_Exhibition_Name,
    T.F_Exhibitor_Name,
    TC.F_CreditNoteNo,
    TC.F_Description,
    TC.F_Price,
    TC.F_Qty,
    TC.F_CNqty,
    TC.F_Totalamt 
FROM T_CreditNote TC 
LEFT JOIN T_Exhibitor T ON 
    T.F_Exhibitor_Name = TC.F_Exhibitor_Name 
WHERE TC.F_CreditNoteNo='CNINV100002'
```

The output looks like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F_Exhibition_Name   F_Exhibitor_Name                            F_CreditNoteNo  F_Description   F_Price      F_Qty        F_CNqty      F_Totalamt                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WORKSPACE 2015      AEP - Associacao Empresarial De Portugal    CNINV100002     item1                12          5             8               96 
WORKSPACE 2015      AEP - Associacao Empresarial De Portugal    CNINV100002     item2                25          12            10             250
```

I want to add one more column `[sum]` at last with sum of `F_total` amount. In my case, I want to show `sum(250+96)` = `346`.

How I can do this?

Comment: In which row this sum will display ? because for aggregate you will have to use group, and by grouping rows will combine into one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SUM OVER()`:

```
select TC.F_Exhibition_Name, T.F_Exhibitor_Name, TC.F_CreditNoteNo, 
       TC.F_Description, TC.F_Price,TC.F_Qty, TC.F_CNqty, TC.F_Totalamt,
       sum(TC.F_Totalamt) OVER () AS SumOfTotalamt
from T_CreditNote TC 
LEFT JOIN T_Exhibitor T on T.F_Exhibitor_Name=TC.F_Exhibitor_Name 
where TC.F_CreditNoteNo='CNINV100002'
```

The windowed version of `SUM` will return for both rows to sum of `F_Totalamt`.

Comment: @jasbacker If your [sum] add for each group of `F_CreditNoteNo`, you may add a `Partition` in `SUM OVER()` like `SUM(TC.F_Totalamt) OVER(PARTITION BY F_CreditNoteNo)`

Comment: @Eric The query simply returns 2 rows because of the `WHERE` clause, hence there is no need here for a `PARTITION BY` clause: The window on which the `SUM` is applied to is simply these two rows.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes you are right, it is just an advice to get the column logic work independently with the where condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUM()` aggregate function like

```
SELECT 
    TC.F_Exhibition_Name,
    T.F_Exhibitor_Name,
    TC.F_CreditNoteNo,
    TC.F_Description,
    TC.F_Price,
    TC.F_Qty,
    TC.F_CNqty,
    TC.F_Totalamt,
    SUM(TC.F_Totalamt) as sum_amt 
FROM T_CreditNote TC 
LEFT JOIN T_Exhibitor T ON 
    T.F_Exhibitor_Name = TC.F_Exhibitor_Name 
WHERE TC.F_CreditNoteNo='CNINV100002'
GROUP BY  TC.F_Exhibition_Name,
    T.F_Exhibitor_Name,
    TC.F_CreditNoteNo,
    TC.F_Description,
    TC.F_Price,
    TC.F_Qty,
    TC.F_CNqty,
    TC.F_Totalamt
```